# python regex comma separated group

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I am trying to create a group of only the items that have commas. So far, I am able to create a group, what I'm trying to do is ensure that the string contains the word nodev. If the string doesn't contain that word, a match should show, otherwise, the regex should not match anything.

String:

```
"/dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4    rw,exec,auto,nouser,async    1  2"
```

Regex that matches the comma delimited group:

```
([\w,]+[,]+\w+)
```

I've tried this regex but with no luck:

```
(?!.*nodev)([\w,]+[,]+\w+)
```

I'm using https://pythex.org/ and am expecting my output to have one match that contains "rw,exec,auto,nouser,async". This way I plan on appending ,nodev to the end of the string if it doesn't contain it.

Looking for a regex only solution(no functions)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm using https://pythex.org/ and am expecting my output to have one match that contains "rw,exec,auto,nouser,async"

Comment: Isn't `string.split()[3]` enough?

Comment: Looking for a regex only solution with no functions

Comment: \s([a-z]+,[a-z,]+)\s

Comment: Are you using `re.search` or `re.match`?  The expression you are currently using works fine for me with the string you list (no "nodev") and one with ",nodev", using `re.search`.

Comment: @TomRon that seems to have solved it

Comment: @mtik00 The issue occurred with adding ,nodev in the middle of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "/dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4    rw,exec,auto,nouser,async    1  2"
>>> s2 = "/dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4    rw,exec,auto,nodev,nouser,async    1  2"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)(?!.*nodev)(?=\S*,\S*)\S+', s)
['rw,exec,auto,nouser,async']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)(?!.*nodev)(?=\S*,\S*)\S+', s2)
[]
```

To append `,nodev`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(?!.*nodev)(?=\S*,\S*)\S+', r'\g<0>,nodev', s)
'/dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4    rw,exec,auto,nouser,async,nodev    1  2'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(?!.*nodev)(?=\S*,\S*)\S+', r'\g<0>,nodev', s2)
'/dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4    rw,exec,auto,nodev,nouser,async    1  2'
```

---

[**pythex demo**](http://goo.gl/Cc3Pyb)

Comment: i think it won't work if both comma seperated values are present within a single string variable.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I think the string came from [`fstab`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab). So it will have one options field (`rw,exec,auto,nouser,async`) per line.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete regex solution.**

For this to work, you need to import `regex` module.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = " /dev/mapper/ex_s-l_home /home  ext4 rw,exec,auto,nouser,async    1  2 rw,exec,nodev,nouser,async    1  2 nodevfoo bar"
>>> m = regex.findall(r'(?<=^|\s)\b(?:(?!nodev)\w+(?:,(?:(?!nodev)\w)+)+)+\b(?=\s|$)', s)
>>> m
['rw,exec,auto,nouser,async']
```